Dx11 screen capture HDR problems
I am using the following code to capture the screen, but when capturing the HDR display, it will be overexposed. Is there any way to convert the HDR image to SDR, or other methods?
I tried changing the Format to Format.FormatB8G8R8A8UnormSrgb but I ended up with a byte[] of all 0s.
There may be something wrong with my understanding of HDR. Any solution to the 'overexposure' problem will be fine.
OutputDesc desc = new OutputDesc(null);
                        if (output->GetDesc(ref desc) != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to get output description");
                        }
                        if (output->QueryInterface<IDXGIOutput5>(out output5) != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to get IDXGIOutput5");
                        }


                        if (output5.DuplicateOutput((IUnknown*)device, ref outputDuplication) != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to get output duplication");
                        }

                        OutduplFrameInfo outduplFrameInfo = new OutduplFrameInfo();
                        Thread.Sleep(20);
                        if (outputDuplication->AcquireNextFrame(3000, &outduplFrameInfo, &desktopResource) != 0 ||
                            outduplFrameInfo.LastPresentTime == 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to acquire next frame");
                        }

                        if (desktopResource->QueryInterface<ID3D11Resource>(out desktopTexture) != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to get desktop texture");
                        }

                        Texture2DDesc stagingTextureDesc = new()
                        {
                            CPUAccessFlags = (uint)CpuAccessFlag.Read,
                            BindFlags = (uint)(BindFlag.None),
                            Format = Format.FormatB8G8R8A8Unorm,
                            Width = (uint)desc.DesktopCoordinates.Size.X,
                            Height = (uint)desc.DesktopCoordinates.Size.Y,
                            MiscFlags = (uint)ResourceMiscFlag.None,
                            MipLevels = 1,
                            ArraySize = 1,
                            SampleDesc = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                            Usage = Usage.Staging
                        };

                        if (device->CreateTexture2D(&stagingTextureDesc, null, ref stagingTexture) != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to create staging texture");
                        }

                        stagingTexture->QueryInterface<ID3D11Resource>(out stagingResource);
                        immediateContext->CopyResource(stagingResource, desktopTexture);

                        MappedSubresource mappedSubresource = new MappedSubresource();
                        if (immediateContext->Map(stagingResource, 0, Map.Read, 0, &mappedSubresource) != 0)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to map staging texture");
                        }
                       
                        var span = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(mappedSubresource.PData,
                            (int)mappedSubresource.DepthPitch);


From the docs for the newest capture api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

On systems with Windows HD color enabled, the content pixel format might not necessarily be DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM. To avoid pixel overclipping (i.e. the captured content looks washed out) when capturing HDR content, consider using DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT for every component in the capturing pipeline, including the Direct3D11CaptureFramePool, the target destination such as CanvasBitmap. Depends on the need, additional processing such as saving to HDR content format or HDR-to-SDR tone mapping might be required. This article will focus on SDR content capturing. For more information, please see Using DirectX with high dynamic range Displays and Advanced Color.

You'll have to do the HDR-to-SDR tone mapping yourself. There is a tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/high-dynamic-range#adapt-hdr-content-to-the-displays-capabilities-using-tone-mapping

Also note there is another possible format for HDR which is DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/high-dynamic-range#option-2-use-uint10rgb10-pixel-format-and-hdr10bt2100-color-space

I tried using Format.FormatR16G16B16A16Float and
var span1 = new ReadOnlySpan<float>(mappedSubresource.PData, (int)mappedSubresource.DepthPitch); but the final data is all 0, I don't understand why

Perhaps try using the newer WinRT api? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframepool

@MakesYT the docs say that you have to use DuplicateOutput1 not DuplicateOutput https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/high-dynamic-range#capturing-hdr-and-wcg-screen-content
